# .NET equivalent for Java wildcard generics <?> with co- and contra- variance?

Tags: java, .net, generics, covariance, bounded-wildcard

I'm stuck trying to translate some Java code that uses (bounded) wildcard generics to C#. 
My  problem is, Java seems to allow a generic type to be both covariant and contravariant when used with a wildcard. For instance:

**Java:**

```
interface IInterf { }

class Impl implements IInterf { }

interface IGeneric1<T extends Impl> {
    void method1(IGeneric2<?> val);
    void method1WithParam(T val);
}

interface IGeneric2<T extends Impl> {
    void method2(IGeneric1<?> val);
}

abstract class Generic<T extends Impl> implements IGeneric1<T>, IGeneric2<T> {
    public void method1(IGeneric2<?> val2) {
        val2.method2(this);
    }
}
```

...works.

*C# equivalent (?)*

```
interface IInterf { }

class Impl : IInterf { }

interface IGeneric1<T> where T:Impl {
  //Java was: 
  //void method1(IGeneric2<?> val2);
    void method1(IGeneric2<Impl> val);
    void method1WithParam(T to);
}

interface IGeneric2<T>where T:Impl {
    void method2(IGeneric1<Impl> val);
}

abstract class Generic<T> : IGeneric1<T>, IGeneric2<T> where T : Impl
{
  //Java was: 
  //public void method1(IGeneric2<?> val2) {
    public void method1(IGeneric2<Impl> val2)
    {
         val2.method2(this); //'this': Argument type 'Generic<T>' is not 
                             //assignable to parameter type 'IGeneric1<Impl>'
    }

    public abstract void method1WithParam(T to);
    public abstract void method2(IGeneric1<Impl> val);
}
```

...fails to compile - see the error in the comment. Which is to be expected, since IGeneric's generic parameter is not marked 'out' for covariance.

If I change this:

```
interface IGeneric1<T> where T:Impl {
```

to this

```
interface IGeneric1<out T> where T:Impl
```

the error goes away, but another one appears, for the declaration of the method that takes a generic parameter inside the same interface:

```
interface IGeneric1<T> where T:Impl {
    void method1WithParam(T val);  //Parameter must be input-safe. 
                      //Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be
                      //contravariantly valid on 'IGeneric1<out T>'.
```

Suggestions?

[Also see the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14289518/11545) for a somewhat harder scenario]

Comment: What is the meaning of the question mark inside the angle brackets in Java?

Comment: "Any type goes" (or in this case, any type derived from `Impl` goes). It's called "wildcard". http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to translate the Java wildcard generic methods to C# methods that are generic in their own right. For example, this:

```
interface IGeneric2<T extends Impl> {
    void method2(IGeneric1<?> val);
}
```

should be translated to

```
interface IGeneric2<T>where T:Impl {
    void method2<U>(IGeneric1<U> val) where U:Impl;
}
```

It is necessary to repeat the type constraint for `T` specified by `IGeneric1<T>` as the type constraint for `U`.

The reason for this is that in the Java version there are *implicit* constraints for the type arguments of the parameters of `method1` and `method2`: if the parameter must be some kind of `IGeneric1<X>` then `X` must obviously be an `Impl` because otherwise it could not possibly implement `IGeneric1` for that type.

In C# the constraints must be explicit, so you repeat what `IGeneric1<T>` and `IGeneric2<T>` require of `T`.

So the equivalent code would be:

```
interface IInterf { }

class Impl : IInterf { }

interface IGeneric1<T> where T:Impl {
    void method1<U>(IGeneric2<U> val) where U:Impl;
    void method1WithParam(T to);
}

interface IGeneric2<T>where T:Impl {
    void method2<U>(IGeneric1<U> val) where U:Impl;
}

abstract class Generic<T> : IGeneric1<T>, IGeneric2<T> where T : Impl
{
    public void method1<U>(IGeneric2<U> val2) where U:Impl
    {
        val2.method2(this);
    }

    public abstract void method1WithParam(T to);
    public abstract void method2<U>(IGeneric1<U> val) where U:Impl;
}
```

Comment: Is the Java version of `method2` actually bounded? According to the documentation the OP posted, a bounded wildcard declares the constraint inline. There is no such constraint in the Java code of the OP. I assume calling `method2` with an `IGeneric1<string>` would be valid.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: There is an implicit constraint in that `IGeneric1<T>` and `IGeneric2<T>` require that `T` extends `Impl`. `method1` and `method2` say "I 'll take any kind of `IGenericX`", but it is not possible to actually *have* a type implement `IGenericX` for just *any* value of the generic type parameter. Unless I am horribly mistaken, because my Java is sub-par.

Comment: Of course, you are correct - that's where the constraint comes from. In C# you have to explicitly "repeat" that constraint on the methods, while in Java this is implicit. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: It does need the constraint because `IGenericX<T>` requires it. The point is that `T` in `Generic<T>` and `U` in `method1<U>` need not be the same type.

Comment: I think you answered to an old version of my comment :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: You type too fast ;-)

Comment: Yes, and I thought too slow to keep up with the typing ;-)

Comment: @Jon Your suggestion worked great - for most part of the codebase, of which my example was just a small part. But I hit another roadblock. Would you mind taking a look at the updated question? Thx

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu: Your update is another question altogether. Please post it as such and reference this one in it.

Comment: @Daniel Good point. Question restored to initial state. Here's the new scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289518/net-equivalent-for-java-bounded-wildcard-iinterf